# Can the mean be a random variable?

Tags: mean, random-variable

Can the mean of some sample of random variables be itself a random variable?

Yes?

---

I think the particular confusion here is that **since the calculation procedure for statistics is known, then they do not seem like "random draws"**. But they can take r.v.s as input and thus could be r.v.s. in the sense of being linear combinations of r.v.s, for example.

Comment: But the mean is also (at least in some cases) the expected value.

Comment: The situation in your question is not sufficiently clear. For example, if you're talking about *sample means* they can certainly be random variables. If you're talking about the population mean for a given random variable, then that's a fixed number (while it could be regarded as a degenerate random variable, it would be unusual to do so with a population parameter). Please clarify the circumstances in your question.

Comment: I'm asking for "mean" in general. Which would ask for an answer considering also means that cannot be r.v.s.

Comment: This is called conditional probability: the mean of $X$ may be $Y$ conditional on $Y$ and $Y$ still be a random variable.

Answer (score 3):

The mean of a collection of random variables is itself a random variable.

So if you have say, $X_1,X_2,X_3,...,X_n$, then $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_n)$ is a random variable.

If you're talking about a sample of particular observations, $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, then you could look at the sample mean, $\bar{x}$ as another kind of observation, relating to the random variable $\bar{X}$ in the same way that the observation $x_1$ relates to the random variable $X_1$, which is to say it's a [realization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_%28probability%29) of the random variable $\bar{X}$.

[On the other hand, when we're talking about the mean of the distribution of a random variable, that is a parameter; it's not a variable $-$ at least not in a frequentist framework; it may be treated as one in a Bayesian framework, in which case it can be taken to represent the uncertainty in our belief/knowledge about its value.]

Answer (score -2):

It's expected value of the random variable. Random variable itself is a function from sample space to real number. If some how one can define this function in a random way one may get random expected values. Given E(X) exist.

Comment: Sorry, your answer sounds a bit vague to me. Can you show by means of an example?

Comment: The mean of a sample is *not* the expected value of the variable.  Perhaps you have misinterpreted the question?